# Is there a way to serialize a c# class to xml without put attributes on the class?

Tags: c#, xml, class, xmlserializer

I would like to serialize a c# class but I do not want to put the attributes on the class.
I've found FluentXML on codeplex, but it seems to be just an idea project and is not working anyway

Comment: why afraid of placing attributes ? they are made to b applied

Comment: I´m not afraid, I just do not want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XmlSerializer` without attributes and live with the default names it gives you or you can also implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface on your class for a more customized but manual output without the need for using attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that worked for me. From [Serialize object to string](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/5d08bc28-5b61-4c5a-8c4b-4665b1c929ea/)

I just googled "serialize class to xml string"

```
String XmlizedString = null;

XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(objectNameHere.GetType());

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

x.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, objectNameHere);

memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;

UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

XmlizedString = encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

XmlizedString = XmlizedString.Substring(1);
```

It produced a string like this
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Name>StackOverflow User</Name><Title>User of StackOverflow.</Title><Salary>70000</Salary><Skills><string>Being Awesome</string><string>Being sweet</string></Skills></Employee>`

From an Employee class as simple as this:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public double Salary { get; set; }
  public Collection<string> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing forcing you to put attributes on your class in order to use `XmlSerializer`. In this case the generated XML will simply reflect your object structure. If on the other hand you want to control the generated XML you could use a `XmlWriter` or an `XDocument` instead. But the attributes are designed exactly for that purpose and you should use them. If for some reason you cannot modify the class you are serializing (because for example you do not have the source code for it) you could always design a different class which you could decorate with attributes and then map the original class to this model that you would serialize.

Comment: It is for a Model dll with more than 100 model classes. I need to extract some of these clases as xml following a specific xsd. I have all the information I need on the model classes but with different names and I do not want to include attributes on some classes just for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a really good reason to not use attributes, you can use `XmlSerializer`, but be aware that it only works on public members and also requires a public type and a parameterless constructor.